# Is there a way to choose a nested field as a partition key in AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a JSON document like:

```
{
  "best_answer": {
    "answers": { 
      "a" :"b",
      "c" :"d"
    },
    "question": "random_question"
  },
  "blurbs": []
}
```

And I want to create the partition key on the "question" field (nested inside best_answer). How to do this on the AWS Console?

Comment: no. it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way this is possible is to add the "question" entity as a top level attribute on the item, in this case the partition key, in addition to being embedded in the JSON. Whether that is a good partition key remains to be seen. I cannot comment on that without know more about your use case and its access patterns to start with.