# New to DynamoDB. Is there a more convenient way to add/put items?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Looking at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetItemCRUD.html#PutItemLowLevelAPIDotNet) example in the AWS DynamoDB documentation, I see that `PutItemRequest.Item` is a `Dictionary`. I'm trying to insert a complex JSON object into DynamoDB that can have anywhere between 200 to 300 attributes within a hierarchy of nested objects and arrays.

Do I really have to convert that JSON object to a `Dictionary` before I can insert it into DynamoDB? If so, is there a way to do this that doesn't involve hardcoding and/or manually converting it one attribute at a time?

Apologies if this question is a little vague. I'm really just looking for pointers on how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation includes an example of how to [Insert JSON Format Data into a DynamoDB Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-json.html#dynamodb-json-insert-table-data):

```
// using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
// using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel;

var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
var table = Table.LoadTable(client, "AnimalsInventory");
var jsonText = "{\"Id\":6,\"Type\":\"Bird\",\"Name\":\"Tweety\"}";
var item = Document.FromJson(jsonText);

table.PutItem(item);
```

More broadly, per the same [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-json.html):

> The AWS SDK for .NET supports JSON data when working with Amazon DynamoDB. This enables you to more easily get JSON-formatted data from, and insert JSON documents into, DynamoDB tables.

Comment: How does it know what the partition key is? Seems like I need to set the partition key somehow, otherwise it throws an exception telling me that the partition key wasn't found.

Comment: The partition key (and sort key, if appropriate) are properties of the item that you send to DynamoDB. *You* supply them, on the item (or in the JSON from which the item is constructed).

Comment: So the JSON item I'm trying to insert does indeed contain both the partition and sort keys, but it seems as though DDB doesn't know where to look for them. Do I not need to explicitly point them out or is it looking for the keys based on the key names that I set when I was creating the tables? If so, should the key names represent a JSON path to where the keys are in the object?

Comment: I should also mention that the partition and sort keys are in a nested object in the JSON, so my partition key is named ".identification.id", and I'm just not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: That seems to be the case unfortunately. It seems that partition and sort keys always have to be top level attributes, so I'll need to manually add those into the JSON before inserting it into the table. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548647/is-there-a-way-to-choose-a-nested-field-as-a-partition-key-in-aws-dynamodb

Comment: Any data you want to be able to query by, index on, etc. has to be a top level attribute.